# Redux-persist not saving all the data in Expo/React Native app

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, redux-persist

I am creating an app with Expo/React Native with Redux. I want to persist data. But all of data is not saving on AsyncStorage. There are 3 keys in store and 2 of them are array and one of them is string. String one is saving but arrays not. You can find all my code in https://github.com/yunisdev/walllet . Can you please help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Expo, so you should use the `ExpoFileSystemStorage`  in order to store the state.

Like this:

```
import { AnyAction, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore, Store } from "redux";
import ExpoFileSystemStorage from 'redux-persist-expo-filesystem';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: ExpoFileSystemStorage ,
  whitelist: ['main']
};

const mainConfig = {
  key: 'main',
  storage: ExpoFileSystemStorage
}

import mainReducer from './reducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  main: persistReducer(mainConfig, mainReducer)
})

const store: Store<any, AnyAction> = createStore(persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer), applyMiddleware(thunk))
const persistor = persistStore(store)

export {
  store,
  persistor
}
```